# How to get the position of a view relative to its parent including padding?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a FrameLayout with a LinearLayout child. I am updating the position of the LinearLayout by setting its bottom padding to 100. However when I get the OnLayoutChange callback, the `bottom` and `oldBottom` are identical.

I have tried `offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords`, `getLocationInWindow`, and `getGlobalVisibleRect` but it doesn't seem like any of these take into account padding.

Here is are my layout files:
activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

</FrameLayout>
```

banner_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/banner_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner_container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/banner_bgcolor">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/banner_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#FF323232"
            android:textColorLink="#FF828282"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Banner text here"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/banner_logotext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#FF828282"
            android:textColorLink="#FF828282"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Logo"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my main activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var bottom = 0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val frameLayout = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.frameLayout)
        val bannerView = frameLayout.addBannerView()
        frameLayout.setOnClickListener {
            bannerView.post {
                bottom += 32
                bannerView.setPadding(0,0,0, bottom)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun FrameLayout.addBannerView(): View {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.banner_layout, this, true)
        val bannerView = findViewById<View>(R.id.banner_layout)
        bannerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener { view, left, top, right, bottom, oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom ->
            val msg = "Difference bottom: ${bottom - oldBottom}\n" +
                "Position top left: (${bannerView.left}, ${bannerView.top})"
            Log.e("MainActivity", msg)
            Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        return bannerView
    }
}
```

Basically, the above code adds the `bannerView` to the `frameLayout` in `onCreate`, and adds an onClick that adds 32dp to the bottom padding of the `bannerView`. The output I get is always like this, even though I can see the view moving up the screen.

```
Difference bottom: 0
Position top left: (0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without code, it's hard to understand what is happening. Please, try to share the code.

But, it sounds like you are trying to update the position of a child view within a FrameLayout by adjusting its padding, but you are having trouble getting the updated position information from the OnLayoutChange callback.

One possible issue is that the OnLayoutChange callback may be called before the padding changes take effect. This could be because the padding changes are not being applied immediately, but rather are being queued up to be applied during the next layout pass.

To ensure that the padding changes are applied before the OnLayoutChange callback is called, you can try using the View.post() method to schedule the padding changes to be applied after the current layout pass has completed. For example, you could do something like this:

```
myLinearLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myLinearLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 100);
    }
});
```

This will ensure that the padding changes are applied during the next layout pass, which should ensure that the OnLayoutChange callback has access to the updated position information.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've added some code to my original post. I tried using `post()` but it did not have any effect.